# Triggerred send validation error log!

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

While saving a triggered send definition I received the below error message. Where do I find this log to investigate my error message!

`The email ID = 17736, contained 4 validation errors. Refer to the Triggered Send Email Validation error log, ID = 1962133841`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Preview & Test Send feature of email studio. When editing the email, select the Preview and Test tab, and follow these steps:

1. Select Preview and Test.
2. To view the email with AMPscript and personalization strings rendered select a list, group, data extension, or audience then select a subscriber.
3. Review the email to ensure personalization displays correctly. The subscriber’s attributes are listed next to the preview.

In step 2, select the data extension, belonging to the triggered send which you struggle to activate. This will validate the ampscript and show you specific errors in the email.

Comment: Super! @Lukas Lunow .... this solved my issue.... Actually the Email was missing the Mandatory Physical Address and Profile center links :-| ... How silly the issue looks once we know how to degug!... Thanks again!

Comment: @VishalKumarCV if you are using a custom profile center, you can ask the support to disable the CAN-SPAM validation on emails.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and still got an error, I don't think it's relevant for my case.

I have tried adding an old working email and it still gives me an error.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Please see the note about "commentary on...other answers" in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that this "answer" will most likely be deleted. Please contribute to SFSE in other ways so that you gain reputation - you only need 15 rep to upvote a post & only 50 to comment under someone else's answer. Or you could *Follow* the Q or A to be notified when updated; or possibly ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) & in it link to this question's other answer for reference.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/177149)